# How to enable header_editor_enable in graphiql-rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6, graphiql

How can i set `header_editor_enable` as `true` in graphiql-rails gem?
There is no graphiql config file in my project. So, I've created it in `config/initializers/graphiql.rb` but I don't know how to set it true.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change with `header_editor_enable` is not released yet as of 02.12.2021.
What you can do is change your Gemfile to point to the latest master of the gem

```rb
# Gemfile
gem "graphiql-rails", git: "https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphiql-rails.git", branch: "master"
```

Then in your initializer, add `header_editor_enabled` option as

```rb
# config/initializers/graphiql.rb
GraphiQL::Rails.config.header_editor_enabled = true
```

You are good to go

[image: screen_shot_of_editor_with_header_section]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've already do it earlier, but forgot to write here the answer. Hope it'll be useful for others.